# How to track Vim open and close time?

Tags: vim

I want to keep a track of when I open or close Vim. Does Vim store its start time anywhere? Or tracking Vim start time from bash_history is a better approach? For example, if I open five times a day, I want to save the different times at which I have opened vim.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to track time using for a Vim session, the simple solution is using GNU [time](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), i.e `time vim some_file.txt`.

Or a more flexible way is using Vim script. For example, add this line in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:start_time = strftime('%c')
```

and then in a vim session

```
:echo g:start_time
```

Comment: While this partially answers my question, I'm looking for a way to store the time whenever I open Vim. For example, if I open five times a day, I want to save the different times at which I have opened vim. I'm sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: @VeeraSivarajan I see, I think the only way to get that information is using Vim script to log opened time for each session to file. Then based on your purpose, it can extract the metrics that you want to have